# How to run mocha scripts on Heroku server?

Tags: heroku, mocha.js

I am trying to run `mocha` scripts, it's working on the local system but not running on `Heroku` server.
used commands:  npm install mocha --save-dev and then : mocha
 please refer to this image.

[image]

Comment: Where did you run those commands? Have you included Mocha as a dependency in your `package.json`?

Comment: I am trying to run commands on Heroku console and added a dependency in the package.json as well.

Comment: Running them via `git bash` won't do what you want. Does your main application run on Node.js, or something else?

Comment: yes, I am using Node.js. I want to run from Heroku console.

Comment: You 100% _can't install_ Mocha via `heroku run bash`. You _must_ install via `package.json` and either `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`. (Running it once it's installed properly should be a different story.) Does the deployment finish cleanly? Do you see Mocha being installed in the output when you deploy?